# Probability of reaching a sales plan

Tags: probability, statistics, finance

I am quite new to probability theory but I am interested in the subject.

My question:

If you have a sales plan of $21,000,000 over 5 weeks, and in week 1 reach 10% (2.1 million) and in week 2 you reach 30% (6.3 million) and in week 3 you reach 45% (9.45 million). What is the probability that in week 4 you will reach 80% and in the last week you will reach 100%? What could be an algorithm/theorem that I could use that will give me the probability (P) that in week (N) I can reach a goal of (X) % ?

Again, I am new to probability and statistics so please go easy on me. I am also not looking for a hand out, I just can't find anything on the internet.

Please let me know if I am missing any information.

Thank you!

Comment: The basic approach would probably be to let $X$ be a random variable that represents the sales achieved for one week. You would pick a distribution for $X$, and then based on that you can calculate the quantities you want. The actual calculation is going to depend on the choice of distribution.

Comment: @dbx Sorry for asking this, but how could I start this? How do I make a distribution based off of the 2.1 million dollar sales for week 1?

Comment: You want to think about all the possible sales amounts that you might have in a given week, and how likely each of them is. For an extremely simple example, maybe you have only two objects to sell, that both cost $\$1$. Then your sales could only be $\$0$, $\$1$, or $\$2$; maybe all three outcomes are equally likely. A more realistic case is that any amount between some minimum and maximum is possible, and numbers near the middle are more likely.

Answer (score 0):

This question is specifically of **statistical inference**. Even more specifically, of **parameter estimation**. You have to find some fundamental information about the scenario then you can start plugging it into formulas and models. See if you can narrow down your search for an answer based on this.

I am interested in this question too but I haven't started on estimation yet. I